# AMD OpenCL 1.1 image3d_t writing in kernel

Tags: c++, opencl

I am writing a GPU ray marcher using AMD's implementation of OpenCL 1.1 (I am using their c++ wrapper api).  Initially, I implemented the kernel using large single dimension arrays for my grided volume and dsm along my own interpolation functions which worked fine.  As a side note, I am doing the dsm sampling using a separate kernel.

Now I am working on re-implementing my code to take advantage of the OpenCL type image3d which has it's own hardware accelerated interpolation function for the volume and dsm.  I have the volume image3d working fine, however I cannot get the dsm image3d working during the ray march kernel.

As I mentioned earlier, I am using a separate kernel to sample the dsm.  From the documentation I read (and the video card device specs), I should be able to write directly to the image3d in my kernel using:

write_imagef( image3d_t image, int4 coord, float4 value );

Where image is the dsm, coord is the x,y,z values for the grid (since I am running the dsm kernel in 3 dimensions this is defined by the global ids) and value is the value at that position.

I am initialising my dsm image3d in my code using:
cl::Image3D(context, flags, format, width, height, depth, 0, 0, host_ptr, &err);

where context is my OpenCL contex
flags = CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR
width, height and depth is the dsm grid width, height and depth
format is a cl::ImageFormat with the following settings:
  format.image_channel_order = CL_RGBA;
  format.image_channel_data_type = CL_FLOAT;
the next two positions are not used, so they are set to 0
host_ptr is a pointer to the original grid
and &err is a pointer to an error object

I enabled cl_khr_3d_image_writes, I also declared my dsm in the kernel as:
__write_only image3d_t dsm.

Essentially, I run my DSM sample kernel then I run my ray march kernel.  I am using the same pointers for both kernel arguments for the image3d data.

I cant think of any other details I can include.

Answer (score 1):

`CL_MEM_READ_ONLY` means that you're only going to read from the buffer. Thus no writes allowed. Use `CL_MEM_READ_WRITE` if you're going to read and write from the buffer.